# Replace Environment variable with bash

Tags: bash, shell

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: "APIKEY",
    authDomain: "AUTHDOMAIN",
    databaseURL: "DATABASEURL",
    projectId: "PROJECTID",
    storageBucket: "STORAGEBUCKET",
    messagingSenderId: "MESSAGINGSENDERID"
  },
  functionURL:"FUNCTIONSURL",

};
```

I have this type of file now I want to replace all variables (`APIKEY`, `AUTHDOMAIN`,..) using bash, please provide some generic solution!

```
sed  -i 's/($APIKEY)/('"$Master_APIKEY"')/g'
```

Already use for every variable in file.

Comment: Not clear, could you please mention more details? Like which file you want to edit? from where variable values should be picked up?

Comment: how is python related in this question? seems like javascript to me

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 file already given and variable value should be anything

Comment: @soheshdoshi if you know what you are replacing exactly then why not just do a `sed "s/$APIKEY/$Master\_$APIKEY"`

Comment: This uses `sed`, which has nothing to do with `bash`.  Do you require `bash` code to do this?

Comment: @soheshdoshi: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: Do you have a variabele called `APIKEY` with the key to be replaced (like `apiKey`), and the new value that should replace the old one in the variable `Master_APIKEY`? Perhaps start writing your shell varables in lowercase now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prepend every variable with the string `$Master_` use:

```
sed 's/\(.*: "\)\(.*\)"/\1$Master_\2"/g' inputfile
```

this command works like this:

- **`\(.*: "\)`**: match everything until the string `: "` and capture in group 1
- **`\(.*\)"`**: match everything before the last `"` and capture in group 2
- **`\1$Master_\2"`**: replace with contents of group 1, followed by `$Master_` and contents of group 2.

output:

```
export const environment = {                                                
  production: true,                                                         
  firebase: {                                                               
    apiKey: "$Master_APIKEY",                                               
    authDomain: "$Master_AUTHDOMAIN",                                       
    databaseURL: "$Master_DATABASEURL",                                     
    projectId: "$Master_PROJECTID",                                         
    storageBucket: "$Master_STORAGEBUCKET",                                 
    messagingSenderId: "$Master_MESSAGINGSENDERID"                          
  },                                                                        
  functionURL:"FUNCTIONSURL",                                               

};
```

you can include the `-i.bak` flag to replace the original file and make a backup file.

Comment: what about FUNCTIONSURL?

Comment: Wif you want to replace `FUNCTIONSURL` too then replace `\(.*: "\)` with `\(.*: *"\)` in the regex in order to match zero or more spaces after the colon.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example for what you are trying to acheive:

P.S. you don't need to cat and all, you can directly use sed -i on the file, this is just to demonstrate a single line code where we are inserting a variable on the given pattern:

```
a=REPLACEMENT ;cat inputfile | sed "s/\"\(.*\)\"/\""$a"_\1\"/g"
```

the output from the input file provided by you :

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: "REPLACEMENT_APIKEY",
    authDomain: "REPLACEMENT_AUTHDOMAIN",
    databaseURL: "REPLACEMENT_DATABASEURL",
    projectId: "REPLACEMENT_PROJECTID",
    storageBucket: "REPLACEMENT_STORAGEBUCKET",
    messagingSenderId: "REPLACEMENT_MESSAGINGSENDERID"
  },
  functionURL:"REPLACEMENT_FUNCTIONSURL",

};
```

Comment: It's give output like  apikey : "REPLACEMENT_xyzv" time for replacing placeholder with environment variable

Comment: @sheshdoshi can u please share more details about the variable and your implementation??